# The way stack handle functions arguments

Tags: c, exploit

I am studying the Format String section of The Shellcoder's Handbook.
As the book advices i use a code like this to do my tests:

[formatstring.c]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if(argc>1) {

        if(argc>2) {
            printf("Push a key to continue...\n");
            getc(stdin);
        }   
        printf("Sortie format string =>  ");
        printf( argv[1] );
        printf("\n"); 

    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

So, i understood the trick is to locate your argument (the chain you pass to formatstring and which is used later by printf) on the stack with an offset.

```
./formatstring "aaaa%$offset\$x"
```

(Setting kernel.randomize_va_space to 0 so the offset remains constant). To find this offset they use a tiny batch script

```
for((i=0; i<1000; i++)); do echo -n "$i " && ./formatstring "AAAAAAAA%$i\$x"; done | grep 4141
```

I got this out (here offset=137)

```
137 Sortie format string =>  AAAAAAAA41414141
138 Sortie format string =>  AAAAAAAA25414141
```

Firstable my "AAAAAAAA" are not "aligned" on the stack (i can only count seven 41 here, but i sent 8 'A' to formatstring), and the way they are placed on the stack seem to change during time => If i launch my bash script (the for) 2 hours later may be the 'A''s "alignment" would have changed.

And more disturbing, the offset seems to change when i add bytes to the argument i send to ./formatstring. If i run

```
for((i=0; i<1000; i++)); do echo -n "$i " && ./formatstring "AAAAAAAA%32x%$i\$x"; done | grep 4141
```

I get

```
136 Sortie format string =>  AAAAAAAA                        b7ff103041414141
137 Sortie format string =>  AAAAAAAA                        b7ff103025414141
```

Or run

```
for((i=0; i<1000; i++)); do echo -n "$i " && ./formatstring "AAAAAAAA%320x%$i\$x"; done | grep 4141
```

I get

```
139 Sortie format string =>  AAAAAAAA                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        b7ff103041410067
140 Sortie format string =>  AAAAAAAA                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        b7ff103041414141
141 Sortie format string =>  AAAAAAAA                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        b7ff103033254141
```

As you can see, the offset change and follow a logic i can't understand. According to the book, none of this should happen. Do you know where it comes from? Is it a kind of stack protection mechanism? Can i remove it when i gcc formatstring.c?

Comment: What architecture are you running this from? Modern processors combined with operating system/compiler support can nullify these sorts of attacks.

Comment: Backtrack 5 intel core i3 x86

Answer (score 0):

Well, i figured it out. The stuff the book doesn't explain (or i misunderstood as you can see english is not my native lang) is that you can only add sets of 16 characters (bytes) to your argument if you want it to keep the same offset on the stack.

So if you add "%320x" to your argument, you also have to complete with (16-5=11) 'A' (or any other character) because strlen("%320x")=5.